# In MVC @Html.RadioButtonFor not calling javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

[image]In MVC Html.RadioButtonFor not called javascript,

**MVC Razor:**

```
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Type, new { @class = "input-group radio", @id = "rdA1", @onclick = "Toggle(rdA1)" }, "Single") @Html.Label("Single")

  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Type, new { @class = "input-group radio", @id = "rdA2", @onclick = "Toggle(rdA2)" }, "Multiple") @Html.Label("Multiple")
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function Toggle(ctrlId) {
    if (ctrlId == "rdA1") {
        alert(1);

    }
    else if (ctrlId == "rdA2") {
       alert(2);
    }
}
```

Thanks

@Stephen Muecke, if i modify your code my design has been changed check here

Comment: Have you checked the resulting HTML in your browser dev tools?

Comment: If you know jQuery, just use `$("#rdA1").click(function () { ... })`. Embedding JS events (started with `on...`) in HTML helper is rarely used.

Comment: `@onclick = "Toggle('rdA1')"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd parameter of `RadioButtonFor()` is the value of the input and the 3rd parameter is the htmlAttributes (you have them the wrong way around). It should be

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Type, "Single", new { @class = "input-group radio", @id = "rdA1", @onclick = "Toggle(rdA1)" }) @Html.Label("Single")
....
```

Note also that your `<label>` elements will not act as labels (clicking on them will not set focus to the associated radio button because they are not associated with the `id` of the radio buttons).

Comment: yes calling js but littile bit issue in design please check my edited qn.

Comment: That is just a matter of styling your elements (previously you were not adding `class = "input-group radio"` which I assume styles the radio button as `block` rather that `inline-block`). And get rid of `onclick()` and use [unobtrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Muecke